# Java string comparison not working?

Tags: java, string, comparison

I'd like to think it's simple but I just can't understand how to do this :( I've tried both == and equals so far but i got neither of them to work. Here's a small programming calculating grades for the swedish highschool system (so just ignore the swedish and look at the string comparisons. The problem here being that the statistics function variables are still set to 0 at the end of the program.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Uppgift1 {
private String[] subjects = {"Matematik","Svenska","Engelska","Idrott",
            "Bild","Fysik","Biologi","Kemi","Historia","Geografi",
            "Samhällskunskap","Religionskunskap"};`

private String[] grades = new String[subjects.length]; // Lika många element som ämnen

public void setGrades() {
    for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++){
        grades[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ange betyg i " + subjects[i] + " (IG, G, VG, MVG)");
    }
}

public void statistics() {
    int ig = 0;
    int g = 0;
    int vg = 0;
    int mvg = 0;
    int points = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++){
        if(grades[i].equals("IG")){
            ig++;
        }

        else if(grades[i] == "G"){
            g++;
            points += 10;
        }

        else if(grades[i] == "VG"){
            vg++;
            points += 15;
        }

        else if(grades[i] == "MVG"){
            mvg++;
            points += 20;
        }
    }

    String output = new String("BETYGSSTATISTIK\n");
    output += "IG: " + ig + "\n";
    output += "G: " + g + "\n";
    output += "VG: " + vg + "\n";
    output += "MVG: " + mvg + "\n";
    output += "Betygspoäng: " + points;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Uppgift1 prog = new Uppgift1();
    prog.setGrades();
    prog.statistics();
}
}
```

Comment: Try again using `equals`. Repost if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to print the grades? Also take into consideration that perhaps the alphabet I am Swedish character is not using ascii

Comment: Yeah I tried now, it works. Also the swedish characters stays out of any calculations so they shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have used the first comparison correctly, but later on, you got it the wrong way some how.

Always use `equals()` method when comparing the content of strings, as you did in the first case.

Also, if its not working somehow, it may be because you have `leading` or `trailing` whitespace in your string. Try using it this way: -

```
if (grades[i].trim().equals("IG"))
```

Comment: Ooh wow it's working. It's strange though since I messed around with both equals and == but I never had all of the statements be equals. Thanks :)

Comment: @Latedi. Yeah, thats good. I saw some spaces in your string, so I thought this might be a problem.

Comment: Yeah I will... It says I have to wait though :( 2 more minutes or so and I'll accept it.

Comment: The tip about using trim() saved me from a pit of despair and bewilderment, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You need to make all the `String` verifications with the `equals` method. Change your ifs to do it, instead of comparing with `==`

Comment: Your little answer made me learn everything again... OMG. Big thanks